# $mainframe->redirect(‘XXXXXXXXXXXX’); not working in IE

Tags: joomla

```
$mainframe->redirect(‘XXXXXXXXXXXX’);
```

not working in joomla although I have defined

```
global $mainframe;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the code like that

```
global $mainframe; 
$redirect = "xxx.php";
$mainframe->redirect($redirect);
```

or

```
global $mainframe; 
$mainframe->redirect($redirect);
```